# Atom/Sublime-Text can't find Nodejs but it's there?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, ide

Note: I'm completely new to Linux and Nodejs and most other related things...
OS: Linux Mint

Issue: I am trying to compile Javascript in either Atom or Sublime but upon doing so get the error for Atom. Atom has two addons (Script & Runner).

```
Unable to run node | Did you start Atom from the command line? atom . | Is it in your PATH? PATH: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

or Sublime:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'node'
[cmd: ['node', '/home/l3ir/Desktop/console.js']]
[dir: /home/l3ir/Desktop]
[path: /home/l3ir/bin:/home/l3ir/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games]
[Finished]
```

Nodejs is successfully installed and I've found its files within those paths (Namely usr/bin). I've done a ton of googling and this is beyond me.

How do I get these programs to recognize and use Nodejs?

I should mention 'npm' might have also been installed alongside Nodejs, if that impacts anything?

Comment: I'll also like any recommendations for an IDE that'll work node javascript out-of-the-box too.